# Running Custom Marks in FancyHdr

Tags: memoir, fancyhdr

I have created a document that contains a book of the bible with chapter and verses. I have developed a header for the document, but it is not updating correctly. At the moment, it recognizes only the last occurrence of "bibchap" and the last occurrence of "bibver". Ideally, it would show the first occurrence of the "bibchapter" and the first occurrence of "bibver", and the last occurrence of "bibchapter" and the last occurrence of "bibver".

For example, if a page began with CHAPTER 2 VERSE 6 and ended with CHAPTER 3 VERSE 4, it would read 2:6 – 3:4.

I have included a MWE.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{dblfnote}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% \usepackage{polyglossia}

% \setmainlanguage{syriac}

% \setmainfont[BoldFont={DejaVu Serif Bold}]{Serto Antioch Bible}

% Make Counters for Chapters and Verses

\newcounter{bibchapter}
\newcounter{bibver}
\setcounter{bibchapter}{0}
\setcounter{bibver}{0}

% Make Bible Chapter and Verses

\newcommand{\bibchapter}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{bibchapter}% Increment the counter
  \chaptermark{#1}
  {\centering{#1}}% Center the chapter title
}

\newcommand{\bibvermark}{}

\newcommand{\bibver}[1]{{\textsuperscript{\textbf{#1}}}
\stepcounter{bibver}% Increment the counter
}

% Make Book Title in English and Syriac

\newcommand{\englishtitle}[1]{\centering\LR{#1}}

% Make Header with Chapter and Verses

\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\setcounter{subsection}{0}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\arabic{bibchapter}:\arabic{bibver}}
\fancyhead[C]{\englishtitle{EXAMPLE}}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}

% \newcommand{\mymarks}{%
%   \ifthenelse{\equal{\leftmark}{\rightmark}}
%     {\rightmark} % if equal
%     {%
%      \ifthenelse{\equal{\leftmark}{\chaptermark}}
%        {\rightmark--\bibvermark} % if not equal, and bibchapter is the same
%        {\chaptermark--\rightmark} % if not equal, and bibchapter is different
%     }%
% }

% Command to Format the Footnotes

\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\oldfootnote{~#1}}

\begin{document}

\bibchapter{1}

\bibver{1}\lipsum[1]

\bibver{2}\lipsum[2]

\bibver{3}\lipsum[3]

\bibchapter{2}

\bibver{1}\lipsum[4]

\bibver{2}\lipsum[5]

\bibver{3}\lipsum[6]

\bibver{4}[7]

\bibchapter{3}

\bibver{1}\lipsum[8]

\bibver{2}\lipsum[9]

\bibver{3}\lipsum[10]

\bibver{4}

\bibver{1}\lipsum[11]

\bibver{2}\lipsum[12]

\bibver{3}\lipsum[13]

\bibver{4}[14]

\bibver{5}\lipsum[15]

\bibver{6}\lipsum[16]

\bibver{7}\lipsum[17]

\bibver{8}[18]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Try searching the site for running headers for dictionaries. I know they've been questions about that and it's the same problem.

Comment: Note that you should not be using fancyhdr with memoir. Memoir has its own well integrated system for handling headers and footers